# Sorting algorithm on dataframe with swapping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following dummy df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'address': [1234, 24389, 4384, 4484, 1234, 24389, 4384, 188],
    'old_account': [200, 200, 200, 300, 200, 494, 400, 100],
    'new_account': [300, 100, 494, 200, 400, 200, 200, 200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   address  old_account  new_account
0     1234          200          300
1    24389          200          100
2     4384          200          494
3     4484          300          200
4     1234          200          400
5    24389          494          200
6     4384          400          200
7      188          100          200
```

**A)** I want to sort it such that I have `200` at `old_account` and directly in the next row at `new_account` again:

```
200 xxx
xxx 200
```

**B)** I further want to sort the non-200s such that I start somewhere let's say with `300` and browse through the whole df looking for `300`s and do the switches:

```
200 300
300 200
200 300
...
```

Only once there are no `300`s anymore I would go to the next, let's say `400`..

```
200 300
300 200
200 300
...
200 400
400 200
200 400
...
```

`df` above should look like this:

```
   address  old_account  new_account
0     1234          200          300
1     4484          300          200
2    24389          200          100
3      188          100          200
4     4384          200          494
5    24389          494          200
6     1234          200          400
7     4384          400          200
```

As you can see, the 200s are diagonal to each other and so are the non-200s.

The following code works only for A). **I did not manage to also make it consider B)**
I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the initial DataFrame
df= pd.read_csv('dummy_data.csv', sep=';')

# Initiate sorted df
sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

while not df.empty:
    # Find the first row where '200' is in 'old_account'
    idx_old = df.index[df['old_account'] == 200].min()
    
    if pd.notna(idx_old):
        # Add the corresponding row to the sorted result
        sorted_df = pd.concat([sorted_df, df.loc[[idx_old]]], ignore_index=True)
        
        # Remove the row from the original DataFrame
        df = df.drop(index=idx_old)
        
        # Find the matching row where '200' is in 'new_account'
        idx_new = df.index[df['new_account'] == 200].min()
        
        if pd.notna(idx_new):
            # Add the corresponding row to the sorted result
            sorted_df = pd.concat([sorted_df, df.loc[[idx_new]]], ignore_index=True)
            
            # Remove the row from the original DataFrame
            df = df.drop(index=idx_new)
        else:
            break  # If no matching row is found, exit the loop
    else:
        break  # If no more '200' in 'old_account' is found, exit the loop

# Reset the index of the sorted DataFrame
sorted_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(sorted_df)
```

Comment: Why getting tied to hard-coded `200` ?

Comment: I need to start somewhere and 200 is the one that will be in every row. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I suggest to find all cross-pairs, having them at the top, and leave all unmatched at the end

Comment: Understood, tried it now but it somehow only partly follows the logic I want. Do you have a code example?

Comment: @Exa have you tried the approach below? If this doesn't work exactly the way you want can you please provide a counter-example?

Comment: @Exa, check if your actual dataframe could have records without cross-pairs, like if we append an additional row to your current input df like values `[222, 333, 444]` ?

Comment: @mozway, If my last comment wil turn out to be true, the Euler graph will get broken

Comment: @Roman in this case you can compute the Euler path on the subgraphs, but yes OP should clarify

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, indeed it does. In fact, it should not. I will clean it up and run my code again. Thus, as mozway stated, the Euler path will currently not work

Comment: @Exa, one more thing: could there be a row with the **same** value for both columns (like `(200, 200)`) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest originally yes, but I already removed these rows before I ran my code. Still working on cleaning my df aka figuring out why it's so messy to begin with throughout the week and then try again. Thanks already

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to search a [Eulerian path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in a directed graph.

You might want to use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org)'s [`eulerian_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_path.html):

```
import networkx as nx

start = 200

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='old_account', target='new_account',
                            create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph)

tmp = pd.DataFrame(nx.eulerian_path(G, source=start, keys=True),
                   columns=['old_account', 'new_account', 'n'])


out = (tmp.merge(df.assign(n=df.groupby(['old_account', 'new_account']).cumcount()))
       [df.columns]
       )
```

Output:

```
   address  old_account  new_account
0     1234          200          400
1     4384          400          200
2     4384          200          494
3    24389          494          200
4    24389          200          100
5      188          100          200
6     1234          200          300
7     4484          300          200
```